# After upgrading to trusty, ALSA midi connection (aconnect) doesn't seem to work right

Tags: sound, alsa, midi

Previously in kubuntu 13.10 I was able to open vmpk or plug in a midi keyboard, and provided that TiMidity was running in server mode, I could run

```
aconnect [keyboard port (129:0 for vmpk)] 14:0
aconnect 14:0 128:0
```

and I could play the keyboard and get sound. But now, a while after upgrading to trusty, I tried to do that, and didn't get any sound. TiMidity itself (`timidity ~/path/to/midi.mid`) still plays files fine, but if I try to play them with aplaymidi, I still just get silence. Oddly, the midi files are clearly being read. When I ran (where 130:0 was vmpk's input port)

```
aplaymidi -p 130:0 ~/path/to/midi.mid
```

vmpk was highlighting notes on the piano as if it were playing the midi. One time I tried this, TiMidity (?) very briefly played a fraction of a second of the first chord of my song before everything went silent and vmpk just highlighted the first voice on the keyboard as usual.

Now the weirdest part of this is that probably about 40% of the time, when I've played at least one note with either aplaymidi or vmpk, when I run

```
aconnect -x
```

I get a sudden burst of a note or chord from my speakers (that is, if I played one note, I get a note; if I played multiple sequential notes, they turn into a chord), as if the notes were being queued up but not being played and that somehow liberated them. I have no idea what's going on there.

A little while ago I remember having a problem with Audacity playing wav files sped up and also locking up if I tried to pause it, which it stopped doing when I set the audio devices to the actual audio devices rather than pulse. But now when I checked again, it's doing the opposite: it won't play audio at all and/or acts weirdly if I *don't* set the audio devices to pulse, and either way will very occasionally randomly do the speeding up thing regardless.

Oddly in the midst of what's looking like a pretty screwed up sound system, sound in VLC and Firefox has been working fine and if I play a wav file with

```
aplay ~/path/to/sound.wav
```

that works fine too.

Any idea what I could do to figure out what's wrong with ALSA and/or fix it?

**edit**: I tried aseqdump. All I got from both vmpk and aplaymidi were a bunch of lines that looked like these; just "note on", "note off", "port subscribed" when I connected to aseqdump, and "port unsubscribed" if I ran aconnect -x in the other tab or the song finished.

```
Source  Event                  Ch  Data
  0:1   Port subscribed            132:0 -> 131:0
132:0   Program change          0, program 34
132:0   Note on                 9, note 35, velocity 40
132:0   Program change          1, program 40
132:0   Program change          2, program 44
...
132:0   Note on                 9, note 35, velocity 40
132:0   Note off                9, note 35, velocity 0
132:0   Note on                 0, note 48, velocity 95
132:0   Note on                 9, note 35, velocity 40
132:0   Note on                 1, note 72, velocity 65
132:0   Note off                0, note 48, velocity 0
132:0   Note off                1, note 72, velocity 0
132:0   Note off                9, note 35, velocity 0
132:0   Note on                 0, note 46, velocity 80
132:0   Note on                 9, note 35, velocity 40
132:0   Note on                 1, note 70, velocity 65
132:0   Note off                0, note 46, velocity 0
132:0   Note off                1, note 70, velocity 0
132:0   Note off                9, note 35, velocity 0
132:0   Note on                 0, note 48, velocity 105
132:0   Note on                 9, note 35, velocity 40
132:0   Note on                 1, note 72, velocity 75
132:0   Note off                0, note 48, velocity 0
132:0   Note off                1, note 72, velocity 0
132:0   Note off                9, note 35, velocity 0
132:0   Note on                 9, note 35, velocity 40
132:0   Note on                 0, note 43, velocity 80
132:0   Note on                 1, note 67, velocity 50
  0:1   Port unsubscribed          132:0 -> 131:0
```

It seems like the burst of sound specifically only occurs when I have vmpk or aplaymidi connected to TiMidity and then either close aplaymidi with Ctrl+C or disconnect vmpk with aconnect -x.

Also, when I try to use fluidsynth, fluidsynth and jackd will both fail if I try to run them because jackd can't access some device named alsa_pcm.

```
$ jackd -d alsa -r
jackdmp 1.9.10
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2013 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
Cannot lock down 82274202 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|48000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
ALSA: Cannot open PCM device alsa_pcm for playback. Falling back to capture-only mode
Cannot initialize driver
JackServer::Open failed with -1
Failed to open server
```

Comment: Very strange. Can you reproduce this by connecting either `vmpk` or `aplaymidi` to `aseqdump`?

Comment: I tried that, and added the results. It really seems like the midis are being read properly but something's just wrong with playback. The alsa_pcm error I got when I tried to install and run fluidsynth (I used to use it on my old computer before I realised aconnecting to timidity was quicker and easier; never had it installed on this computer before) might be relevant.

Comment: I have no idea what the problem was here. I "solved" it by reinstalling Kubuntu 14.04, under which somehow JACK works great and there are basically no audio problems now (sometimes KDE complains the sound system failed when playing system sounds, playing them anyway about half the time it says such, but that doesn't really bother me). I'm commenting rather than answering because I feel like this is really not an answer to the question, even though my problem is solved.